# Java Freemarker template datetime in correct format

Tags: java, datetime, freemarker, localdate

I am using https://freemarker.apache.org/ library in my java application to populate xml.
For creation time I am unable to get it as expect (see below):

Expected:

```
<creationTimestamp>2019-10-07T09:09:54.786Z</creationTimestamp>
```

Actual:

```
<creationTimestamp>2019-10-08T19:38:35+01:00</creationTimestamp>
```

I am using `<creationTimestamp>${.now?datetime?iso_local}</creationTimestamp>`. How can I display the timestamp as expected and is there a way? Or, what would be Java 8 way LocalDateTime of doing this if not possible with expression?

Comment: You are right, iso_utc outputs the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

```
Basic formats:
${aDate?iso_utc}
${aTime?iso_utc}
${aDateTime?iso_utc}


Basic formats:
2011-05-16
21:32:13Z
2011-05-16T21:32:13Z
```

iso_utc gives the result as expected.